# Joint distribution with specified marginals

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we are given a probability distribution over a finite discrete product space $p(x,y)$ with marginals $p(x), p(y) > 0$ for each $x,y$ respectively. We are given two more marginal distributions $r(x), r(y)>0,$ for each $x,y$ respectively. Can we always find functions $f(x), g(y)$ such that

$\sum_y p(x,y)f(x)g(y) = r(x)$

$\sum_x p(x,y)f(x)g(y) = r(y)$?

It appears that we should always be able to do this, but I would like an explicit expression for a solution $f,g$ in terms of $r(x), r(y).$ Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the generalized matrix scaling problem and several other names.  Both the theory and associated algorithmic problems have been studied. I suggest you start with [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-006-0021-4) and the papers it cites.

Answer (score 0):

There are some notational issues.  The two different marginals and the joint distribution for X and Y need to be distinguished by different choice of symbols. My suggestions are: $p(x,y), p_X(x), p_Y(y)$, and similarly  $r_X(x), r_Y(y)$.
Now your question is existence of $f(x), g(y)$ such that
$\sum_y p(x,y) p_X(x) g(y) = r_X(x),$ and similarly the other one.
As the LHS is a summation over $y$, it must be a function purely one $x$.

Now using your hypothesis that you are in finite discrete space the existence  of $f(x), g(y)$ can be interpreted as a question of  existence of solutions to two  linear system of equations.

Comment: The question appears to generalize the problem of scaling the rows and columns of a nonnegative matrix in order to make the matrix doubly-stochastic.  That can always be done under some weak conditions, but it certainly cannot be done by solving linear equations.  It is much harder than that.

Comment: Looks like I have not given the problem much thought.